# Convert string to JAXBElement using Java

Tags: java, jaxbelement

I'm having some issue while converting String object to JAXBElement string object where I need to set this one

This is the target method where I need to set the value

```
public void setData(JAXBElement<String> value) {
    this.data = ((JAXBElement<String> ) value);
}
```

For this one, I have written code something like this

```
 ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    JAXBElement<ApplicationIngestionRequest> jaxbElement =  new JAXBElement(
            new  QName(ApplicationIngestionRequest.class.getSimpleName()), ApplicationIngestionRequest.class, request);

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext context =  JAXBContext.newInstance(ApplicationIngestionRequest.class);
    context.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxbElement, writer);
    LOG.info("JAXBElement object :\n"+ writer.toString());
    Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<ApplicationIngestionRequest> o = (JAXBElement<ApplicationIngestionRequest>) u.unmarshal(new StringReader(writer));
```

Log gives me following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ApplicationIngestionRequest><BranchCode></BranchCode><SourceCode>0000005511</SourceCode></ApplicationIngestionRequest>
```

Now when I try to set into the method as

```
losRequest.setData(o.toString());
```

It doesn't allow me to set as its expecting as JAXBElement format. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) What is `o`? 2) Why do you cast `value` to the same type with which it is declared (it's unnecessary)? 3) Calling `toString()` on any object returns a ... well, it returns a string, not a `JAXBElement<String>`. What exactly are you trying to achieve? 4) "It doesn't allow me." What error do you get?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I have updated the question.. I just want to convert that XML output as JAXBElement string so that I can set it in that method.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code snippet [setData(JAXBElement value)] , setData , accept instance of '(JAXBElement'). But here , you are trying to set a string value [losRequest.setData(o.toString())] . Here you have to set an instance of 'JAXBElement' .This could be the issue.

Comment: Can you tell me how do you convert that XML object into JAXBElement String object?

Comment: Please try this , new JAXBElement(o.toString());